# Can QSignalMapper forward function arguments?

Tags: c++, qt

How could I use QSignalMapper to map multiple check box?
The signal from check box I would use is `stateChanged(int flag)`. During the process I want to keep this `int flag` and it will be finally send to my custom slot with other mapped variables.

How could I achieve this？ I am using Qt4.

Comment: With only these information it is really unclear what you are trying to do. Why can't you just connect the `signal` to a `slot` and process it from there? Why do you want to use a `SignalMapper`?

Comment: Perhaps you could start from [**this tutorial**](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html) to understand what does [**`QSiganlMapper`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details) really do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly forward function arguments with a `QSignalMapper`. There are two ways to work around this.

1. Rewrite a custom version of `QSignalMapper` that takes the appropriate function arguments and forwards them.
2. Connect the check box signal directly to the slot you want and check the return value of `sender()` in the slot to see which check box emitted the signal.